# How to compare and separate an array of object list according to one or two of its key's

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Hi I'm trying to find a way to compare an array with its own and group them.

I have an Array Group

```
group= [{name:'Anandapriyan',age:21,home : {door:1,street:'xyz'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}},
        {name:'Mano'        ,age:27,home : {door:1,street:'xyz'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}},
        {name:'James'       ,age:27,home : {door:8,street:'pqr'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}},
        {name:'Anandabalan' ,age:27,home : {door:7,street:'asd'}, currentAddress : {door:9,street:'try'}}]
```

I need to compare this array and form a new Array like this

```
newGroup = [[{name:'Anandapriyan',age:21,home : {door:1,street:'xyz'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}},
             {name:'Mano'        ,age:27,home : {door:1,street:'xyz'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}}],
            [{name:'James'       ,age:27,home : {door:8,street:'pqr'}, currentAddress : {door:2,street:'abc'}}],
            [{name:'Anandabalan' ,age:27,home : {door:7,street:'asd'}, currentAddress : {door:9,street:'try'}}]]
```

Here i am comparing the array with its own elements and grouping them by which ever matches the key values i am comparing
The fields i used to compare is each element of group Array's home & currentAddress values(which are object's). It's easy to compare plain string or integer and group them as below

```
 var result = _.chain(group)
        .groupBy("name" && "age")
        .pairs()
        .map(function (currentItem) {
            return _.object(_.zip(["compared key","newGroup"], currentItem));
        }).value();
 console.log(result)
```

my sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/vxz996c3/) i used lodash library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) can also receive an iteratee function, which creates the identity of the item to group with ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unpgxqyx/)):

```
var groupBy = ['currentAddress', 'home']; // props to group by

    var result = _(group)
    .groupBy(function (item) {
         return groupBy.reduce(function(str, prop) { // concat all prop values into a string for the _.groupBy to compare
            var propValue = item[prop];

            str += str + _.isObject(propValue) ? JSON.stringify(propValue) : propValue; // stringify objects
            return str;
        }, ''); 
    }).map(function (item) {
    return item; // just return the array
    })
    .value();
```